# Regex for this dashed pattern

Tags: regex

Would anyone have a suggestion for a regex that manipulates line that **ends** in:

,04-721-0G-00033-AU

and transform that string into:

,04,721,0G,00033,AU

(replaces all dashes after last comma in a string into commas)

Keep in mind that there could be preceding parts of the string that have dashes and commas, so what I know for sure is that the part of the line I want manipulated is a string that starts with a **last comma in the line**, **ends with EOL** and has this structure of **,XX-XXX-XX-XXXXX-XX**

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the host language? Python, Java, sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match: `,(?=[^,]*$)(\w{2})-(\w{3})-(\w{2})-(\w{5})-(\w{2})$`
Replace by: `,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5`

How it works:

- `,(?=[^,]*$)` selects the last `,` of the line (literally: *the `,` that is only followed by anything but an other `,` until the end of the line*).
- after that, we try to match your **XX-XXX-XX-XXXXX-XX** with
  `(\w{2})-(\w{3})-(\w{2})-(\w{5})-(\w{2})`
- make sure that the end of the line has been reached by matching `$`

Then you just rewrite:

- the `,`
- each **XX** group separated by a `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Would this pattern ([test replace](http://regexr.com?37t2d)) do what you like?

```
-(?=[^,]{1,15}$)
```

Replace with `,`

Checks at hyphen, if there are 1-15 charcters left to end that are no commas using a [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), if so replaces with comma.

As no language is specified, **for a multiline replace**, you might want to add the [m-modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for *multiline*, for JS additional the [g-modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for *global* ([test with modifiers](http://regexr.com?37t2m)).